# How do I refresh an activity in android with new variables from another activity

Tags: android, date, android-activity, fragment

I am working on a android application, and at the moment I have an myActivity, where I have a button with the current time (using setTitle() with a variable 'date').

When I click on this button, I open a datepicker. In this datepicker I can change the date and store it. Now I want to update the button in the myActivity.

How can I 'refresh' this activity and set the title of the button to the newly chosen date? Without losing the changed variable?

I have tried public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I know it stored the new date (by debugging), I just need to reload it in a way.

Comment: Just create the datepicker inside your Actvity and use its onDateChanged() to do your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you're recreating the Actitity with an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), you can add Intent extras:

```
yourIntent.putExtra("Date", date.toString());
```

and retrieve it in onCreate():

```
date = getIntent.getStringExtra("Date");
```

To change the titlebar though, you should only need to do this:

```
setTitle(date.toString());
```

Comment: Excellent, I'll give this a try! Looks promising!

Comment: Where do I put yourIntent.putExtra("Date", date.toString());

Comment: put it between `Intent someVarName = new Intent(ClassName.class);` and  `startActivity(someVarName)`

Comment: Though you should really try the third snippet first if you don't already have the lines above comment in your code.

Comment: I used put the setTitle(date.toString()); in my onResume() function, and call the onResume() when I close the datepicker. This seems to work, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

there are many solutions for that you can try the put extra thing, you could use a static variable, and best for me i would prefer using delegate as follows:

```
//creating an interface that will be responsible for refreshing date
OnDateChanged.java
public interface OnDateChanged
{
    ondatechange(X x);/* x is your date value of type date*/
}

// create your custom dialog
DatePickerDialog .java
public class DatePickerDialog extends Dialog
{
    private OnDateChanged mListener;

    public DatePickerDialog (Context context, OnDateChanged listener )
    {
        super(context);
        mListener = listener;
                  ........
        }

       ......
       // on certain click you call this 
       mListener.colorChanged();
}


// implements OnDateChanged here
MyActivity.java
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnDateChanged
{
...
    @Override
    public void ondatechange(X x)
        {
              // do something with date "x" 
    }
....
// creating dialog goes here on click or something
new DatePickerDialog (context, this).show();
}
```

this works as best solution when u need to update a ui element in MyActivity that tracks date